# What does "1 consecutive" mean with respect to the consecutive days count?

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I visited [SU](https://superuser.com/) today for the first time after a short break and noticed:

[image: image showing "Visited 108 days, 1 consecutive"]

As far as I know, it is not possible to have "1 consecutive" of anything. I am not sure what it should be, maybe nothing should be here until there are at least "2 consecutive" days to report.

Is this an oversight (or perhaps there is a logical explanation)?

Comment: I think the logical explanation is the desire not to introduce too many conditionals. It's simpler to just use "%d consecutive" and dynamically replace the placeholder. However in this case it kind of sticks out like a sore thumb to me. 108, 1 consecutive is weird. I agree it should not be displayed if there is not more than 1.

Comment: Or perhaps it should actually be "0 consecutive" if there is not more than 1. Maybe that makes the logic a little simpler (just replace 1 with 0).

Comment: +1 - This has annoyed me for a long time. Not dealing with special cases is just lazy coding.

Comment: @CaveJohnson I guarantee that there will be users complaining that “0 consecutive” suggests that they have never visited the site for two or more subsequent days, until that is they click on the calendar icon, and see for themselves the  dates of their “daily visit”.

Answer (score 9):

It's explained pretty well in the answer to [Use of the term "consecutive" to describe a single item](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/365172/use-of-the-term-consecutive-to-describe-a-single-item), on Stack Exchange itself:

> First note the context in which these examples are presented - namely in the context of programming.
> It is true that colloquially we would not say that there is one consecutive instance of the digit 1. However, in the more formal setting of programming it is desirable to handle exceptions without dealing with special cases. This is because case handling is generally considered to be inelegant in programming.

It's about something bit different,  but fits in this case as well, where it's applied to a single day.

If you want this changed, it's possible to start a feature request asking to hide the whole element in case there are less than two consecutive days, as Cave Johnson [mentions in this comment as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396695/what-does-1-consecutive-mean-with-respect-to-the-consecutive-days-count#comment1326835_396695).